# Android Things UserSensor: how should I set the accuracy of a sensor?

Tags: android, android-sensors, temperature, android-things

I have one temperature sensor that provides values with 0.25 °C of resolution but has an accuracy of ± 3 °C.

So if I get 23.75 °C it could actually be anything between 26.75 °C and 20.75 °C. How can I specify this using the `UserSensor.Builder()`?

Should I use `setResolution()`? And what value should I provide? 6? 3? 0.25?

**Edit**
I just want to explain why this feature could be needed: I might have multiple sensors of the same kind, each with different accuracy, and I would like to take the one with better accuracy.

For example I can have my sensor, with resolution of 0.25 °C and an accuracy of ± 3 °C, and another temperature sensor with resolution of 0.5 but accuracy of ± 1 °C. I would like the system to pick the second sensor since the accuracy is better than the 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

> "I have one temperature sensor that has an accuracy of ± 3 °C. So if I get 23.75 °C it could actually be anything between 26.75 °C and 20.75 °C. How can I specify this using the UserSensor.Builder()?"

There is no method for setting sensor accuracy in [UserSensor.Builder](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/userdriver/UserSensor.Builder.html).

> "Should I use `setResolution()`? And what value should I provide? 6? 3? 0.25?"

According to the [HAL documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/hal-interface#sensor_t), `resolution` is *"the smallest difference in value that the sensor can measure. Usually computed based on maxRange and the number of bits in the measurement."*

As your sensor *"provides values with 0.25 °C of resolution"* you should use [setResolution()](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/userdriver/UserSensor.Builder.html#setResolution(float)) with the value for setting its resolution, not accuracy.

> "I might have multiple sensors of the same kind, each with different accuracy, and I would like the system to pick the one with better accuracy".

The system can't do it for you. You should implement an algorithm for "picking the right" sensor. As a criteria you could take the one with higher accuracy according to specification of the sensors.

Comment: The use case is the following: a system can have multiple temperature sensors with different accuracy, I would like for the system to pick the one with better accuracy, similarly to what happens with the location service when both GPS and network are available.

Comment: @Roberto Leinardi, _"similarly to what happens with the location service when both GPS and network are available"_ I believe it happens not on the "system-sensor-level". There is some level of abstraction whose implementation decides which sensor it trusts the most among the signals measured by the system... Anyways, I edited the answer

Comment: _"Doubt, the system can do it for you. Implement an algorithm that would pick the "right" sensor. As a criteria you could take the one with higher accuracy :)"_ But how do I know which one has the higher accuracy if there is no way to specify that in the `UserSensor`? And why the `SensorEventListener` has a callback `onAccuracyChanged()`?

Comment: @Roberto Leinardi, can you distinguish which sensor a signal came from (after setting sensors names or UUIDs)? If so, you know each sensor's accuracy (w.r.t its specs)... Can't really say much about `onAccuracyChanged()`. I guess one can write an own implementation of `UserSensor` class for location and notify via the listener when accuracy has changed, say, from km to m, according to some internal algorithm...

Comment: @Roberto Leinardi, can you extend `UserSensor` and `UserSensor.Builder` adding some `setAccuracy()` method?

Comment: the sources are not available and the library is providing only stubs for the documented public methods (that are also final btw).

Comment: @Roberto Leinardi, I was talking about inheritance and adding a new method, not overriding a final method of parent... The key point is that you cannot set accuracy via `UserSensor.Builder`. I have answered your questions. By me, the part about "different accuracy" is a subject of discussion and your concrete implementation, not system.